# In SpringBoot configuring, how do the classes of @Import get turned into a globally accessible List of classes?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, autowired

I have inherited some code that involves SpringBoot, `@Import`, and `@Autowired`. The code works, but I don't understand why. Can someone tell me what is going on?

In Spring Boot configuration code I have code much like this:

```
@Configuration
@Import({ FirstCombo.class, SecondCombo.class, ThirdCombo.class })
public class MyProgramConfiguration {
    ...    
}
```

The (FirstCombo, SecondCombo, ThirdCombo) all extend the Combo class.

Then there is a business logic class that has this:

```
public class MyBusinessLogic {
    @Autowired private List<Combo> combos;

    public void doSomething() {
        for(Combo c: combos) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

The method `MyBusinessLogic` has access to the List containing the imported Combo classes.  It works in the real world.  My best guess is that when `@Import` does its work it creates a globally available `List<Combo>` instance.  But I'm unable to find documentation that this is what is really happening.

Can someone tell me what is really going on with this sort of code?

Thanks,

Jerome.

Answer (score 0):

It's here
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation

> It is also possible to provide all beans of a particular type from the
> ApplicationContext by adding the annotation to a field or method that
> expects an array of that type:
>
> public class MovieRecommender {
>
> ```
> @Autowired
> private MovieCatalog[] movieCatalogs;
>
> // ... } The same applies for typed collections:
> ```
>
> public class MovieRecommender {
>
> ```
> private Set<MovieCatalog> movieCatalogs;
>
> @Autowired
> public void setMovieCatalogs(Set<MovieCatalog> movieCatalogs) {
>     this.movieCatalogs = movieCatalogs;
> }
>
> // ... }
> ```

You  can try also with

```
@Autowired
private List<Object> allObjects;
```

To fetch all available beans in your class.